# how to create backgroud service in flutter

Tags: flutter

how to create a background service in FLUTTER
with posh notification 
I create an app but I went to integer a service to check the database when the app is not run

thank tou

Comment: Have you looked into Firebase?

Comment: no i have a custom api

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler), which allows you to create CRON jobs which can send a request to your API, on a regular basis. The first three jobs are free.

If you also need to implement the actual function checking your database, have a look at [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/?). Those can be written in Javascript or Typescript and call make calls to external APIs as long as you are on Blaze Plan (which includes the monthly free quotas).

The advantages are:

- you get [free credit](https://cloud.google.com/free) when you create your account
- depending on your needs you might not need more than the [free monthly quota](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing) for Google Functions calls (first 2 millions invocations are free every month)
- it's very easy to create a scheduled function which will picked up and run by the Cloud Scheduler
- it's highly scalable and reliable so you don't have to worry about managing your own servers